# How could I assign the owner of /proc/PID/maps?

Tags: linux, file, privileges, proc

In my system, there is a user program (not a root program) running:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 16 11:28 /proc/*****/maps
```

but another user process "vim" is:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Mar 16 11:28 /proc/*****/maps
```

I am wondering how could I control the owner of /proc/PID/maps of a binary? During compile time or during execution time?

Comment: perhaps the first program is running from root or did sudo?

Comment: what does `ps` of these two processes say?

Comment: ps of the 1st one: `0 S 28022  3401  1409  0  80   0 -   509 n_tty_ pts/0    00:00:00 target`

Comment: ps of the 2nd one: 
`0 S  1000  3405  1409  0  80   0 - 12143 poll_s pts/0    00:00:00 vim`

Comment: From your `ps` I cannot deduct where the user names are to compare them to the names given in the question.